# ElasticSearch track_scores sorted query performance impacts?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to wrap my head around what the performance hit is on queries with and without the track_scores flag flipped in the sort during queries in our ElasticSearch 6.8 cluster. Unfortunately it's pretty busy and I feel like I was unable to isolate enough variables to tease out what the performance hit actually was. I actually got the average score tracked sorted query to be faster than untracked queries, which is the opposite of what I was expecting.

Has anyone found a meaningful performance hit? Or does anyone know what the factors are with the track_scores flag and how they affect searches? Perhaps a ballpark on the % inefficiency in query time?

Thanks!